# What are the acceptable values for EXTERNAL_MASTER_DATABASE_VERSION?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to configure a remote master using Google Cloud's SQL service.  I'm following the doc seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/replication/configure-external-master).

I'm at step #1 which wants me to run the following CLI commands after replacing the tokens:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data '{"name": "[INTERNAL_MASTER_INSTANCE_NAME]",
          "region": "[REGION_NAME]",
          "databaseVersion": "[EXTERNAL_MASTER_DATABASE_VERSION]",
          "onPremisesConfiguration": {"hostPort": "[IP_ADDRESS:PORT]"}}' \
 -X POST \
 https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/instances
```

I'm getting the following error due to the database version I've passed:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid value for: 5.6 is not a valid value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value for: 5.6 is not a valid value"
 }
}
```

I am running MySQL 5.6.33 as my master.  I've tried 5.6, 5.6.33, 5, and I've even tried 1 thinking maybe the attribute ID is misleading and they really want to know which version of the SQL service I would like to use (Gen 1 or Gen 2 - remote masters are only supported in Gen 1).

My question is what are the accepted values for EXTERNAL_MASTER_DATABASE_VERSION?  I can't seem to find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the possible values in the API reference [1]:
MYSQL_5_5
MYSQL_5_6
MYSQL_5_7

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/insert#request-body